# Where to find angular-xeditable and ajax together work simple example

Tags: ajax, angularjs, x-editable

Now, I am using angular-xeditable.I want to send edit data to server.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <a href="#" id='username' editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
</div>
```

and js code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);


app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'awesome user'
    };  
       $http.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/test", {"name":name})
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.data = data; 

      })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $scope.status = status;
});    

});
</script>
```

I received name variable is empty value.
This code doesn't work.I can't find error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke your code that posts to the server on the `onaftersave` event, which is documented here: http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#onaftersave

This event is called after the changes in the inputbox have been set on the model.

In your HTML put the function call in the `onaftersave` attribute like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <a href="#" id='username' onaftersave='postName()' editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
</div>
```

In your controller create the postName function which actually posts the data to the server. Your code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);


    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.user = {
            name: 'awesome user'
        };

        // Called on the onaftersave event of xeditable
        $scope.postName = function () {
            $http.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/test", {"name": $scope.user.name})
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.data = data;

                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                    });
        }
    });
</script>
```